# Undirected connected graph - Finding edges with specific weight that belong to MST

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

the question:

> Given an undirected connected graph G, with  weight on its edges and specific weight X,
> write algorithm that's finding all the edges in G with weight X that belong to some MST of G

apparently you can do it in linear time complexity O(V+E).

- my approach here is to sort the edges(ascending order), then remove all edges of weight X and above, run DFS on the graph, then to check every edge of weight X if when adding the edge, the graph is connected, if so then this edge of weight X does belong to a MSB

but i think im missing here something in the algorithm(what if i have a cycle where all the edges are of weight X for example), and about the time complexity sorting will take (E * Log(E)), DFS will take O(V+E) is (V+E) better or worse then (Elog(E))?

and in addition i need to check for each edge that im "checking" if the graph is still connected (so how could i do that in O(V+E)? wouldnt running dfs again would take more time because i need to run dfs - as the amount of edges of weight X)?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in linear time by adapting [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm):

1. Make the subgraph of G containing only edges with weight less than X;
2. Find the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) of this subgraph, and label each vertex with a number corresponding to its connected component;
3. Find all the edges with weight X that connect vertices with different labels, or with at least one unlabeled adjacent vertex.  Each of those is in at least one MST.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, looking at the algorithm you answerd my question (It's almost the same as what I did) but i still have the same wondering about the time complexity.

Comment: What do you see that could take more than linear time?  There is no sorting and no walking through cycles in here.

Comment: you are correct, in step 1 i was thinking you need to sort first but you can just run on all edges instead, and the same for step 3, thank you